# How to copy from Vim to system clipboard using wayland and without compiled vim `+clipboard` feature flag

Tags: vim, clipboard, wayland, vim-registers

I cannot copy into the `+` or `*` register.

`:echo has('clipboard')` from within Vim returns `0` meaning I don't have that feature flag, I don't want to recompile.

I'm running wayland so I cannot use [X11 based solutions](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/84/how-can-i-copy-text-to-the-system-clipboard-from-vim)

Comment: Possibly related plugin: [fauxClip](https://github.com/Jorengarenar/fauxClip)

Comment: For neovim users: If you have `wl-clipboard` installed, neovim automagically uses it

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I had trouble finding resources so here is what ended up working by adding in `~/.vimrc`.

```
nnoremap <C-@> :call system("wl-copy", @")<CR>
```

`wl-copy` is a [Command-line copy/paste utilities for Wayland](https://github.com/bugaevc/wl-clipboard) and it will copy the piped content you give it to system clipboard.

**What mapping above achieves is**

1. Activate the mapping with `Ctrl + @`. or choose any convenient key combo

   - `nnoremap <C-@>`
2. take the contents of the `"` register,

   - denoted by the `@"` argument
3. and pipe contents of `@"` as an argument to the system `wl-copy` function

   - shown by `:call system("wl-copy", @")`.

**[Alternatively](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/84/how-can-i-copy-text-to-the-system-clipboard-from-vim#answer-21202)**

Assuming you only want to copy line sections of the file, do `shift`+`v` to go into visual mode and only highlight the lines I want to copy. Then do.

```
:'<,'>w !wl-copy
```

where

- `'<,'>` - means you used visual mode to select a range (you don't type this)
- `w !{cmd}` - write the range to the stdin of `cmd`, see more at `:help w_c`

You can map that with

```
xnoremap <silent> <C-@> :w !wl-copy<CR><CR>
```

- `xnoremap`: mapping will work in visual mode only
- `<silent>`: mapping which will not be echoed on the command line
- `<C-@>`: desired key combination
- `:w !{cmd}`: write the range to the stdin of `cmd`
- `<CR><CR>`: two enters are needed otherwise command line waits for another command

Answer (score 3):

Install the `wl-clipboard` package.

Then, adding this to `~/.config/nvim/init.vim` (NeoVIM) works well for me:

```
set clipboard=unnamed

let g:clipboard = {
    \   'copy': {
    \       '+': ['wl-copy', '--trim-newline'],
    \       '*': ['wl-copy', '--trim-newline'],
    \   },
    \   'paste': {
    \       '+': ['wl-paste', '--no-newline'],
    \       '*': ['wl-paste', '--no-newline'],
    \   },
    \ }
```

Comment: In neovim (at least in version 0.9.5, but I suspect even in much older versions) if `wl-clipboard` is installed then it is automagically selected. Make sure to restart neovim after installing.

Answer (score 1):

The feature the author is asking for will be hopefully implemented in vim. See for details: https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/5157

There is also a workaround plugin: https://github.com/jasonccox/vim-wayland-clipboard

As for me, I'm using my own workaround:

```
" Yank into all these at once:
"     vim y/p register
"     wayland primary
"     wayland clipboard
xnoremap <silent> <leader>y y:call system("wl-copy --trim-newline", @*)<cr>:call system("wl-copy -p --trim-newline", @*)<cr>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using neovim, it automatically uses wl-copy under wayland, so after wl-copy is installed everything shall work without additional cofigs.